# How to sort date with jquery tablesorter which is in format 'dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy'

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am having date in dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy format. How to sort this with jquery tablesorter. I try to sort it with sorter:"shortDate" and dateFormat:'ddmmyyyy' but it doesn't sort it in correct order.

```
<table>
<thead> 
    <tr><th>Date</th></tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>
<tr class="reportcell  odd ">
    <td>
        <div class="time">28/04/2014 - 11/07/2014</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="time">28/04/2014 - 13/05/2014</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="time">22/07/2014 - 22/07/2014</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="time">22/05/2014 - 22/05/2014</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How should it sort the two cells with values "28/04/2014 - 11/07/2014" and "28/04/2014 - 13/05/2014"? Which one should come first?

Comment: 28/04/2014 - 13/05/2014 should come first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a custom parser to be able to sort a column. There is an issue with this parser as it would be difficult to make it work properly with the filter widget ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3572/)):

```
$(function() {

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: "date-range",
        is: function(){
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s, table, cell) {
            var dates = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\s](\d{1,2})[\/\s](\d{4})/g, "$2/$1/$3").split(' - '),
                parsed = [];
            if (dates.length) {
                $.each(dates, function(i,d){
                    var v = new Date(d);
                    parsed.push($.type(v) === 'date' ? v.getTime() : d);
                });
            }
            return parsed.length ? parsed.join('') : s;
        },
        parsed : true,
        type: "text"
    });

    // call the tablesorter plugin
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers : {
            0 : { sorter: 'date-range' }
        }
    });

});
```

---

Update (question from comments):

The format function code does the following:

- Modifiy the date by changing it from "dd/mm/yyyy" to "mm/dd/yyyy" so the date parser (`new Date()` will recognize the desired date setting)
- The `split(' - ')` breaks apart the date range and creates two dates in an array from the range string.
- `dates.length` makes sure we have an array with content
- `$.each()` cycles through each date string

  - It creates a data object from the string
  - Then adds it to a new array as either a date in milliseconds or the original string if it isn't a valid date
- It the returns the new array joined together (time in milliseconds of both dates) or the original string if there wasn't a date range.

So, the reason why this method won't work with the filter widget is because the dates are combined (as a string, not added) to allow proper sorting of the parsed date. Also, from writing this description out I realize that a cell with a single date will not get parsed into a time in milliseconds, but instead be returned as the original date string. Either way non-date range cells will sort separate from the date range cells.

Comment: Thank it works quite well... please can you explain the code because I am new to JS. Only the fn inside format index.