# tablesorter sort by date period / date format dd.mm.yyyy - dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have the following table:

```
    <?php 
    $reqSQL = "SELECT * FROM data_cursanti , clients WHERE  start_course > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ORDER BY data_cursanti.name ASC ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexiune, $reqSQL) or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($conexiune)); // sql query for results than the table
    $counter = 1; // for rows counting
    echo '<table id="users" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th width="3%">No.</th>
    <th width="15%">Name</th>
    <th width="10%">Company</th>
    <th width="7%">Course</th>
    <th width="10%">Course Period</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>'
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date1 = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row['start_course']));
    $date2 = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($rand['end_course']));
    echo
    '<tr>
    <td width="3%">'.$counter.'</td>
    <td width="15%">'.$row['name'].'</td>
    <td width="10%">'.$row['company_name'].'</td>
    <td width="7%">'.$row['course_type'].'</td>
    <td width="10%">'.$date1.' - '.$date2.'</td>
    </tr>'
    $counter++;
    } //end while loop
    echo '</tbody>
    </table>'; //close table
```

and using the following parser (slightly modified from here:[How to sort date with jquery tablesorter which is in format 'dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990440/how-to-sort-date-with-jquery-tablesorter-which-is-in-format-dd-mm-yyyy-dd-mm)) for tablesorter to sort by my course period column (the column uses date format dd.mm.yyyy - dd.mm.yyyy):

```
$(function() {

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: "date-range",
        is: function(){
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s, table, cell) {

            var dates = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\.](\d{1,2})[\/\.](\d{4})/g, "$2/$1/$3").split(' - '),
                parsed = [];
            if (dates.length) {
                $.each(dates, function(i,d){
                    var v = new Date(d);
                    parsed.push($.type(v) === 'date' ? v.getTime() : d);
                });
            }
            return parsed.length ? parsed.join('') : s;
        },
        parsed : true,
        type: "text"
    });

// and calling the parser after this script like this: 


    $(function() {
$("#users")
.tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra'],  headers: {0: {sorter: false}, 4 : { sorter: 'date-range' }, {sortForce: [[0,0]]})
.tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), size: 20});
});
```

the problem is that the table gets sorted by dd (day) part of the first date, instead of month as I would like it to be!. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong? Could somebody please modify my code to sort the table data by the mm (month) value of the first date? I have like almost zero knowledge of javascript ... Thankyou!

LE: Also I tried to use the solution presented by mottie in the first answer but the table just breaks down and won't sort anything when I add the 4 : { sorter: 'date-range' } piece of code in the script.

Comment: i don't have any knowledge of this plugin, but seeing your code i see that the parser type is set to 'text'. Is it possible that you must define it as 'date' in order for the sort to work properly (assuming that 'date' is a legal identifier in this plugin)?

Comment: seemed like a good idea ... bat that din not changed anything in the sorting structure ... still sorts by day instead of month ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the dates in this question are separated by periods and the regexp for the other question was using regex which only looked for forward slashes or spaces ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tjpnfLL1/)).

This regexp will work with mm-dd-yyyy dates separated by "`-`", "`/`", "`.`" or "" (spaces).

```
var dates = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[-./\s](\d{1,2})[-./\s](\d{4})/g, "$2/$1/$3").split(' - ')
```

Also, the `sorter` setting needs to target the last row:

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        4: {
            sorter: 'date-range'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, this works on the demo page, but not on my actual site. after changing the code as you suggested, i still got the dates sorted by day instead of month. I have the dates stored in a mysql db in yyyy-mm-dd format and call them in the table via strtotime and a variable like this: 

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)  )
    $date1 = date('d.m.Y',strtotime($row['start_course']));
    $date2 = date('d.m.Y',strtotime($row['end_course']));
and echo'
    <table>
    //rest of the table code
    <td  width="10%">'.$date1.' - '.$date2.'</td> // interest line
    //closing table'

Comment: Each row is a new table (`echo '<table>` within the while loop)? Does the table HTML not match what is seen in the question? Can you modify the demo to duplicate the problem you are havingf?

Comment: first there is <table><thead>column headings</thead> than <tbody> in html, than the while loop with echo for the table rows/cells in php code, than php closes and </tbody></table> back to html. I'll try to modify the demo asap, still need to figure out how to setup a db there! Thank you for your patience, I'm relatively new to php, mysql and very new to jscript.

Comment: modified my question here, maybe this would give more insight towards what I am doing wrong! Thanks

Comment: I don't see any issues in the updates, but I don't know php that well... as long as the HTML you posted before is the result, then it should be okay. The javascript looks good. Are you seeing any errors in the console (Press F12, then console tab) in the browser? What version of tablesorter are you using? What version of jQuery?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2, tablesorter Version 2.0.5b, the dates are stored in mysql in yyyy-mm-dd format, the php changes the format to d.m.Y before they are displayed in while loop.  I did not knew that javascrip errors are shown in the console (as I said I am knew at javascript and relativelly new at php) ... so I checked as you suggested and I got this error: "TypeError: $.type is not a function
parsed.push($.type(v) === 'date' ? v.getTime() : d);" hope this helps!

Comment: LE: LE: I tryed to change $(function() to jQuery(document).ready(function($){... and made shure that the jQuerry is loaded before the $(function(){  ...  but that did not solved my problem :(

Comment: It looks like the problem is that jQuery v1.4.3 is when [`$.type()` was added](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/).

Comment: If you can't update jQuery, change that line of code to `parsed.push(v instanceof Date && isFinite(v) ? v.getTime() : d);` ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjpnfLL1/3/)) - also, if you use the latest version of jQuery, you'll need to also update tablesorter - check out this [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)

Comment: that fixed everything! Thank you for your patience with me and for this great script! (I updated both jquery and tablesorter and used the code from your first answer)